# How do I create a containing page div with css shadow?

Tags: html, css, containers, shadow

I'm trying to create a page container, where the actual page content has a drop-shadow border, containing the page content, separate from the header and footer.

It should look like this effect:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwLGG

A: body background

B: page container

C: header

D: content/sub-header

The style I currently have is this:

```
.page-container {
background: #FFFFFF;
box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
width: 75%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

But it doesn't do anything, it only adds a bottom drop-shadow when a p tag is present.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kgr9hs3q/

Comment: would you create a fiddle for it?

Comment: Image doesn't seem to be right link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`outline` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) instead, it does not affect other elements around and can be used like a border (since, from your image, it's just one color kind of border).

An example:

```css
#container {
  outline: 41px solid #CCC;
  position:relative;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
#header-text{position:absolute;z-index:1;top:0}
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="header-text">This is text in a paragraph</p>
  <div id="container">
    <p>This is text in yet another paragraph</p>
    <p>This is text in yet another paragraph</p>
    <p>This is text in yet another paragraph</p>
    <p>This is text in yet another paragraph</p>
    <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=1bc768be1b3c" title="This is an image">
    <p>This is text in yet another paragraph</p>
    <p>This is text in yet another paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For anything other than text, this doesn't seem to work. The content ends up going below.

Comment: @JWTomic what do you mean? I just added an image inside the content area to exemplify.

Answer (score 0):

apparently your container has no height resulting in a blank div. unless u add some elements into it or give it a static height, you won't see it.

Comment: i've added a height now, but now it's gone full-width and the shadow isn't all the way around.